# How to securely save secret key on disk?

Tags: security, passwords, string-hashing

I am building an application that connect to a 3rd party app to get some info, my idea was to design it in a way that the app control the password, it can change it once in a while, hash it and keep the hashed password somewhere. this way no human knows the password.

But I can't figure out where and how I should securely store the secret key, so the people that have access to that machine can't recover the password.

Is there any known method that I can't find? 
or this is not possible to have the password and secret key on the same machine.

Comment: If it's gonna be hashed , how can they know the password ?

Comment: having hashed password + secret key = knowing password !!

Comment: Think like this: You are trying to make a program which stores a value which is unretrievable from any program. Why would your program be different from any other to be able to retrieve it?

Comment: @Desaroll I get your point, can I assume that this is not possible and stop perusing this idea?? Is it impossible to secure part of a disk for just an application ? I understand that I can't rehash the secret key cause it needs a new key to be stored somewhere.

Comment: Even OS's user password are accessible from a program with enough privileges. You can't retrieve them as they are saved using one-way hashes (They compare the hashed passwords) but you can change them.

Comment: There are "good enough" methods (The password will be invisible for most users), but none are able to resist a serious attack.

Comment: @Desaroll can you please mention this methods name, or where can I read more about them ? thanks

Comment: One is the one you was thinking about. A double way hash with a hard-coded key. To find your key, the user has to be able to browse through the compiled binary. Any common user won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can definitely hide it but what you can do is :

### Windows

- Hide it in a chosen path by using the `attrib` command (`attrib +s +h
  filepath`).
- Deny access to all users with the `cacls` command (open command line and enter `cacls /?` for more). The command should be something like
  `cacls filepath /D user`. That will totally deny the file access to
  the specified user (no possibility to read or write in it). However,
  I think you will need administrator rights in order to do that. You can retrieve the user list with the command `net user`.

### Linux

Apply the same strategy :

- Hide it by preceding its name with a dot
- Deny permission by using the `chmod` command